# 'bundle' reserved word in django??`

Tags: python, django

I have a project I am working on and I create a table called bundle. I also have a foreignkey in another table that references the bundle table. When i try to access the foreignkey, it tells me that bundle is a keyword that is reserved. I also tried checklist and get the same error. I looked online and it didnt show that bundle or checklist is a reserved or keyword. can anyone help me with this. Here is the code that I have and is giving me the error. It is the second of the two lines. Thank you.

```
bundles = Bundle.objects.filter(group = currentGroup).all()
items = Items.objects.filter(bundle.group = currentGroup).all()

  File "/Users/omarjandali/Desktop/yap/opentab/tab/views.py", line 695
    items = Items.objects.filter(bundle.group = currentGroup).all()
                                ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should access the related model's field using two underscores, not dot:

```
items = Items.objects.filter(bundle__group = currentGroup).all()
```

Comment: What tutorial have you been reading? You should see the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) :)